# Upload files from client's in server

Tags: java, php, jsp, curl

I have an applet running in server.It generates some files using the command prompt in client system and is stored in C: drive.Now,I want to upload those files onto the server.How can I do that?

Comment: Server generate some files and store it in client's system??

Comment: Using the command prompt in client's machine and using an .exe file (which is stored onto client from server) the files are being generated

Comment: So you mean from a web application you want to upload that file to server? Am I right?

Comment: There are 10 different .dat files generated using the .exe file.I want to upload all these files.Using data from all of them,again some code will run to generate the final result.I want to upload them via an applet which is already running.I don't know if I am clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirements, [JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/) works well for you. Go to home page to see more information on this and for sample code.

```
JUpload takes care of the limitation posed by traditional HTML upload forms 
by allowing you to upload a whole directory and the files within it 
with a single click.
Its more usual use is as an applet. But it's also available as stand alone 
application.
```